# Adding File Uploads to PHP Mailer

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I love the PHP form I have and how it works, but can't figure out how to add the functionality to upload image files to it. I've spent the past couple hours googling various resources and experimenting with adding what seems to be correct, but haven't had any actual success.

I realize there's lots of information out there on this but I guess I just can't get my head around where and what to add to the code I have now (my experience with using and editing PHP is incredibly limited). This is probably very simple when it comes down to it and I feel silly asking at all but ultimately I haven't been able to get it on my own and I'm hopeful someone can point me in the right direction!

The form I am using:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
    $name = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), array(" ", " "), $name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    if (empty($name) OR empty($message) OR ! filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }
    $recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";

    $subject = "New message from $name";

    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Phone: $phone\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }
} else {
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
?>
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can add attachments to the emails sent using the PHPmailer library with the "addAttachment" method (if you provide the path of the file) or the "addStringAttachment" method (if you provide the content of your file):
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial

If you have trouble uploading a file on your server from an HTML file upload field, make sure you added the following attribute to the  tag:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

In the PHP part, you will find the file's name/path in $_FILE, just move it where you want on your server. You can find some examples on this page: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for commenting! Just to clarify, this method is for visitors for the site to upload files to be submitted w/ the contact form?